# How to use html or wordpress to login to an existing angular app

Tags: html, angular, wordpress

I want to create a membership site (either using html or wordpress) with a login form that will redirect the user to a running angular app (probably in another subdomain).
Is it possible?
Can I carry authentication information along with the redirection so that I can check if the user of the angular app is a member?
Thank you!

Comment: The question is too broad to suggest anything. Yes, you can use WP to authenticate users and use ng to build the template. What exactly is the problem and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WP or HTML with server-side code using PHP / ASP for the log-in process. 
And once verified with the database that the user exits, you can navigate to your angular app. Send the auth token along with the navigation, so that you can authenticate the user from angular with that token. I think it doesn't matter if it is a different sub-domain or not.